# How to call the model file in concrete5?

Tags: php, concrete5

I have one folder called reports inside my project root folder which made of using concrete5. Inside report folder there is one php file.In that php file i want to call the model file which present inside models folder. In that php file,its not accepting any concrete5 keywords.Eg:I tried to print the base url using `echo BASE_URL;` but it not working.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify your question as the english makes little sense ?

Also could you include :-

The version of Concrete 5 your using.
Code examples including any namespacing